# Python 3.9.8, hashlib and RIPEMD160

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, macports, hashlib

Running MacOS 10.14.6. Just ran MacPorts update. Took Python 3.9.7 -> 3.9.8 and OpenSSL 1.1.3 -> 3.

Running existing Python code reveals that something broke with `hashlib` and RIPEMD160 is no longer available (nor Whirlpool and probably other digests).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/hashlib.py", line 160, in __hash_new
    return _hashlib.new(name, data, **kwargs)
ValueError: [digital envelope routines] initialization error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testhash.py", line 3, in <module>
    r160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/hashlib.py", line 166, in __hash_new
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)(data)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/hashlib.py", line 123, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type ripemd160
```

Can replicate simply with

```py
import hashlib
r160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
```

The method `hashlib.algorithms_available` shows that `hashlib` thinks `ripemd160` *is* available:

```
Available:  {'sha512', 'shake_128', 'ripemd160', 'sha224', 'md5', 'whirlpool', 'blake2b', 'sha3_512', 'md4', 'sha3_256', 'sha256', 'shake_256', 'md5-sha1', 'sha1', 'sha512_224', 'sm3', 'mdc2', 'blake2s', 'sha3_384', 'sha3_224', 'sha512_256', 'sha384'} 
Guaranteed: {'sha3_512', 'sha512', 'sha1', 'shake_128', 'sha3_384', 'sha224', 'md5', 'sha256', 'sha3_224', 'sha3_256', 'shake_256', 'blake2b', 'blake2s', 'sha384'}
```

and asking `openssl` confirms it *does* have that capability.

Rolling back, same problem. I'd prefer to keep the up-to-date installation. Use of RIPEMD160 is not negotiable.

I have a suspicion that giving `ports` the correct switches, commands, env vars will convince a recompilation to work but I know not what.

Any ideas on what has happened, how to fix?

Comment: Not sure why `openssl` confirms its availability but RIPEMD160 has been deprecated since OpenSSL 3.0: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RIPEMD160.html

Comment: That was my understanding. Though, to be precise, `openssl` reports `rmd160`, which I take to be RIPEMD160.

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the correct openssl your Python was linked with? MacOS comes with LibreSSL which is aliased to openssl which is a bit confusing. What does `openssl version` say?

Comment: You were correct. There was some confusion with versions and specific libraries.

Comment: I see that others have complained vociferously about deprecating RIPEMD in OpenSSL, given its widespread use. Are there libraries that will keep RIPEMD on?

Comment: You may also try a pure Python solution such as [this one](https://github.com/jcook/python-crypto-debian/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD160.py) from [`pycrypto`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the old crypto functions are still there in OpenSSL3 but now require manual enabling. See [issue 16994 of OpenSSL github project](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16994) for details.

To quickly enable it, find the directory that holds your OpenSSL config file or a symlink to it, by running the below command:

```
openssl version -d
```

You can now go to the directory and edit the config file (it may be necessary to use sudo):

```
nano openssl.cnf
```

Make sure that the config file contains following lines:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect

[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect

[default_sect]
activate = 1

[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```

Tested on: OpenSSL 3.0.2, Python 3.10.4, Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS aarch64, I have no access to other platforms at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

A less than ideal and temporary solution is to:

1. roll-back OpenSSL

```sh
port activate openssl @1.1_3
```

2. remove the installation of Python (after roll-back to previous version if necessary)

```sh
port uninstall python39
port clean python39
```

3. recompile Python

```sh
port install -s -f python39
```

Comment: Rollback openssl to 1.1.1 solved a similar problem for me